# passing arguments to public function in php

Tags: php

```
public function rsMADARIS($Regid, $per_page = "", $offset = "") {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name;
        $sql .= " WHERE Regid='" . $Regid . "'";
        $sql .= " AND ExamYear=" . $this -> a_Year;
        $sql .= " AND Courseid='" . $this -> a_Courseid . "'";
        $sql .= " AND Examtype='" . $this -> a_Examtype . "'";

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . $per_page;
        $sql .= " OFFSET " . $offset;

        return self::find_by_sql($sql);
    }
```

When I am calling this function , I am facing following error.

> Undeclared variable: OFFSET
>   Why it is not working? However $Regid variable working nice but  $per_page , $offset is not working.

Comment: Probably your `$offset` is an empty string (by default), so change your code to: `public function rsMADARIS($Regid, $per_page = "", $offset = 0)`

Comment: cause you passing in query so may be must have value or need to check empty if not then pass in query

Answer (score 2):

If the "undeclared variable" is "OFFSET" then you are writing `$OFFSET` somewhere and you haven't given us your real code. `$OFFSET` and `$offset` are two different variables.

This in addition to the syntactically invalid query you're generating - you should use correct default values.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `$per_page` and `$offset` as null calling your function, it is converted into empty strings which is causing syntax error. Change your function declaration into:

```
public function rsMADARIS($Regid, $per_page = 10, $offset = 0)
```

Comment: thanks alot now it is working nice , public function rsMADARIS($Regid, $per_page = 10 /* or some other default value */, $offset = 0) {